# ffmpeg seeking in HLS m3u8 video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm having problem seeking in m3u8 hls video.
The m3u8 has 9-10 sec .ts fragments, with `#EXTINF:<time>,` before each fragment.

The entire video is 5 hours long and I'm trying to get clip from `3:10:00` to `3:45:00` like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 3:10:00 -i 'http://example.com/v/vod.m3u8' -t 0:35:00 -c:v copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mp4
```

When I execute that, it just waits forever. I tried both on Windows and Linux with the latest and older version of FFmpeg. I waited for like an hour yesterday and it didn't do anything. Log:

```
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://example.com/v/vod.m3u8':
  Duration: 05:25:27.08, start: 60.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:2: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

And it stays like this forever.

How can I seek to 3h10m without having to download the entire 5h25m?
`-ss` doesn't seem to do much

Is it supposed to go so slow or is the `m3u8` corrupted? It looks like this inside:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#ID3-EQUIV-TDTG:2015-12-16T03:24:26
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT

#EXT-X-ELAPSED-SECS:0.0
#EXT-X-TOTAL-SECS:19527.08
#EXTINF:9.268,
index-00000-vdyz-0.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
index-00001-AiD9-0.ts
(...)
```

And it has 12x `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY`, every ~174 parts.

When I use VLC or any other player to open the m3u8 directly I can seek without problem and it's instant. FFmpeg doesn't seem to use the same method of seeking, or it's broken.

To see what I mean, try seeking on this m3u8:

```
http://vod167-ttvnw.akamaized.net/07e4ac668a/lirik_7709808752_7709808752/chunked/index-dvr.m3u8
```

and try fast-seeking (-ss before input) to 2:30:00 and exporting 1 frame with `frames:v 1 out.jpg`

Comment: It takes long because it doesn't skip to the required index and downloads all segments sequentially. I'll take a look at the source. In any case you could make your own script to download the required segments and simply concatenate them.

Comment: @aergistal that's what I'm doing right now, but I was hoping ffmpeg can do it.

Comment: Has this been fixed?

Comment: @BobRoss No, I just tried it. It downloads the videos from the beginning until it reaches the part at 2:30:00

Comment: It seems that if I create the hls file using `-hls_playlist_type event` and use a recent FFmpeg version it works fine.

Comment: @BobRoss The issue is only when I stream the hls, not when it's already on my drive.

Comment: @VixinG I'm also streaming the HLS and capturing it on a different server where I seek to a point in time (while it's live) and it works as expected. 
I also use `-live_start_index 0` on the capturing end.

Comment: @BobRoss...newcomer to this thread. I've tried hls_playlist_type event and upgrading to ffmpeg version 4.2.2. Do you mind sharing: your ffmpeg version, the command your running, and a url for a stream that works? I'm struggling.

Comment: @tslater Do you have an m3u8 link where you cannot seek that we can check for you? For me, recently when downloading some episode, I realised (via Chrome browser's Developer Tools) that their server does not allow accessing any `.ts` file ahead of their own player. It loaded two files at a time then, when the player reached 10 or 20 mins, I would see two more TS files being loaded. If I seeked in the player then some `blob` file was loaded before the relevant two ts files where also loaded... Let's see what's going on with your link.

Comment: I've realized what the issue is. It is working, it just grabs the first few frames at the beginning first, so that was throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you need to use the map flag to assign only stream 0:0 and 0:1 as the third stream(0:2) is timed_id3 and not a video or audio which confuses ffmpeg i have had similar issues while encoding a hls stream for example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 3:10:00 -i 'http://example.com/v/vod.m3u8' -map 0:v -map 0:a -t 0:35:00 -c:v copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mp4

or

ffmpeg -ss 3:10:00 -i 'http://example.com/v/vod.m3u8' -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -t 0:35:00 -c:v copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mp4
```